# Access struct enum from object

Tags: c++

I am just learning to use c++ and I'm trying to understand how scope works with classes and embedded enums.

Currently I have a class which looks something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();

    enum Option = {
        FIRST,
        SECOND,
        THIRD
    };

    struct Example = {
        const char* name;

        Option key;

        enum keyOption = {
            PROPERTY,
            FLAG
        } keyValue;
    };
};
```

Then in my main function I initialize it and then add some values to the `Example` struct

```
int main()
{
    Foo *test;

    Foo::Example content = {
        "Hello World",
        test->FIRST,
        test->Example::PROPERTY
    };
}
```

With the above code I will get an error of:

> error: 'Foo::keyOption' is not a base of 'Foo'

I know I can fix it by changing `test->Example::PROPERTY` to `Foo::Example::PROPERTY`

But is there a way I can access the `Example` structs values through the object instead of `Foo::`? Similarly to how I access the `FIRST` value?

Forgive me if I'm butchering the naming of difference concepts, I'm just trying to teach myself by building something, and I will need to read more into the details soon.

Thank you so much for any help, it is really appreciated!

Comment: `Foo::Example::PROPERTY` and `Foo::FIRST` is the correct way. What's wrong with that? Why are you looking for something else?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I had just seen it the other way a few times. So I was under the impression that I should be doing it another way. Thank you very much for your quick comment. I will change it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foo::FIRST and Foo::Example::PROPERTY are possible values of the enumerator. Only Example::key and Example::keyValue are members of the struct which can be instantiated and initialized to Foo::FIRST and Foo::Example::PROPERTY

Comment: Now that I am looking at the code this makes more sense. I was just trying to do it the other way because of my lack of understanding of the language. Thanks for helping me understand!

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
Foo::Example content = {
    "Hello World",
    test->FIRST,
    Foo::Example::PROPERTY
};
```